# Windows form show list items

Tags: c#, winforms, list, get, output

I have saved the input to the list how do I make it appear in the textboxes in the next form?
This is my code so far.

Form1 (where the textbox is)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 a = new Class1();
            a.minLista.Add(textBox1.Text);
            Form2 Form1 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            Form1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

the class where the list is

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{

    public class Class1

    {
        public List<string> minLista = new List<string>();
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you creating a list to save one textbox value,you can also store it in a string variable.

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly ???

Comment: I am going to have a number of textbox values thats why I want to make a list.
I want the input from the textbox1 in form1 to be printed in a textbox on form2. (I will later add more textboxes and more forms where it should be outputted

Answer (score 1):

Define the List as

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public class Class1

{
    public static List<string> minLista = new List<string>();
}
}
```

and in the **form1 load** write as

```
txtVal.Text= Class1.minLista[0];
```

Comment: txtVal is that the textbox name?